# scala 2.10Mx with playframework 2

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

How to use scala 2.10Mx with play 2.x.x?

I tried adding scalaVersion := "2.10.0-M3" to project/Build.scala but had no effect.

Here's my project/Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "dashboard-server"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    resolvers += "Local Ivy Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.ivy2/cache"

    scalaVersion := "2.10.0-M3"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.10"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here

    )

}
```

I'm using sbt 0.11.3

Comment: In principle, that ought to work if placed in the correct place. Please show the full `Build.scala`. By the way, you need SBT 0.11.3 to use Scala 2.10.

Comment: Until Play has a release based on Scala 2.10.x, you cannot use Play + Scala 2.10.x together.   Scala 2.9.x and 2.10.x are not binary compatible.

Comment: Two gurus of Scala with different opinions...who is right?

Answer (score 2):

There is a ticket in the play bugtracker: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/650-support-for-scala-210-m6

The answer is you currently cannot use play 2 with scala 2.10 because of akka.

Answer (score 2):

play 2.0.x doesn't work with Scala 2.10.
the Play 2.1 branch does, but as of the time i write this (25 Oct 2012), you need to build the development branch from source, and the development branches are still under active development. TLDR: not yet suitable for production apps, give it a couple months

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you can do it. I described details in my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15675008/226895)**.

But in few words you need to specify few things in `Build.scala`.

Switching version by setting `scalaVersion` to `2.10.1` didn't help me because SBT still goes to repository and gets pieces of 2.10.0. So I told SBT to use local copy of Scala by setting following variables

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.1-local",
autoScalaLibrary := false,
scalaHome := Some(file("/Program Files (x86)/scala/"))
```