# how do I fix a bug in the scala-library.jar

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, serialversionuid

I am building a Play! Framework application using Play! 2.2.1, sbt 0.13.0, and my local version of scala is 2.10.3.

I have encountered a serialVersionUID problem when deserializing a particular file that I inherited from coworkers for working on this project (I have no idea who created this serialized file (or when)).

My error message, when building in Play!:

`Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8184381945838716286, local class serialVersionUID = -8707880168089396949`

After much searching, I found this patch that is supposed to fix the bug SI-5046:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5046

I downloaded the scala source code from github for branch 2.10.x and I applied the patch to WrappedArray.scala here: scala/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.scala

What do I do with this modified source code so that I can use it in my Play! application?

*** EDIT #1:

I followed the links from @Alexey Romanov

I'm still getting an error message about WrappedArray$ofRef when I compile Play, though now it is a different error message. Here is what I did:

I rebuilt the scala distribution using ant, using:

`ant build`

`ant partialdist`

Then in Play! I specified the scala version to use for SBT and plugins by adding the following to my Build.scala file:

`scalaVersion := "2.10.3"`
`autoScalaLibrary := false`
`scalaHome := Some(file("/path_to_my_rebuilt_scala_distribution"))`

Now my error message is:

`Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef; incompatible types for field bitmap$0`

EDIT #2:

I'm moving down the Scala versions and when I got to 2.9.2, the error about WrappedArray$ofRef was fixed by applying the patch. Now I am getting another serialization error for a different class:

`java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.Symbol; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3681772905693662441, local class serialVersionUID = 7747205442425187939`

I will move down to Scala 2.9.1 and see if I can get to the contents of the file with that version.

* EDIT #3:

In scala version 2.9.1-1, I get a different serialization error:
`java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.Tuple2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3990034604647285925, local class serialVersionUID = 5867822941721784448`

No idea what to try next.. keep going down scala versions, or are there other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried running `ant` to make a build of the scala binaries?  (http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/)

Comment: I am rebuilding with ant right now. How do I get play to recognize this new build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To use a local Scala installation for building a project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scala.html#local)
 define `scalaHome`:

```
scalaHome := Some(file("/path/to/scala/home/"))
```

Also see [How can I change version of Scala that is used by Play, SBT and its plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674406/how-can-i-change-version-of-scala-that-is-used-by-play-sbt-and-its-plugins) if you end up having to rebuild Play as well.

EDIT: I actually looked at the bug description. It looks like the patch will allow serializing/deserializing `WrappedArray` created by two different Scala versions *which both include this patch*. Since

> (I have no idea who created this serialized file (or when))

it probably won't work for you. And judging from the new error message, it may be that the version of Scala it was serialized with simply didn't include the fields 2.10.3 does and it's impossible to deserialize. My best suggestion is to try deserializing with different Scala versions going down (probably not 2.10.*, since they are binary compatible) and see which one works.

Comment: I'm now trying to compile with Scala 2.9.2. The problem with WrappedArra$ofRef serialization error is gone, but there's a new serialization error in scala.Symbol. I'll edit my question above.